# Create custom map overlay (polylines) [Mapbox]

Tags: gis, mapbox, openmaptiles, fluttermap

I have a Flutter project using flutter_map and tiles from Mapbox. I also have a very large list of coordinates to create polylines on the map. The coordinates are worldwide geographical boundaries. It's working fine but when displaying the polylines the map gets a bit unresponsive due to the amount of polyline data.

How would I be able to create a custom map with the coordinates/polyline data already embedded in the map to avoid having to draw polylines separately?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Mapbox Studio](https://docs.mapbox.com/studio-manual/overview/) to create a map style with [sources](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/sources/) and [layers](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/layers/) referencing these coordinates/polyline data. [This tutorial](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/create-a-custom-style/) on creating a custom style is a great place to get started.